# spring kafka message processing telemetry

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to create some kind of "kafka message processing graph" - which service is consuming which topics and what messages - with some additional metadata(processing duration, whether it was processed OK or it ended with exception,...).

I could create some interceptor that would be invoked before each message processing, but in interceptor I don't know whether there is some handler for this type of event, nor do I know whether message was later processed OK or it ended in error handler.

For checking whether there is some handler I suppose there is some registry i could peek into (?), but is there also some way of wrapping message processing (like filters in spring-mvc) so I can calculate processing duration and end result?

Answer (score 0):

Micrometer timers have been supported since 2.3 (for successes and failures).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer

You can also add an AOP around advice to your listener beans.